Cascading Combo Boxes Do Not Display Correct Value After Requery
I've been searching the web to figure out how to solve the issue.  I've started to design a database which tracks transactions to an account.  It utilizes a cascading combo boxes:
Field = Type
RowSourceType = Value List
RowSource = "Income";"Expense";"Credit"


Field = Category
RowSourceType = Table/Query
RowSource = 

    SELECT CategoriesExtended.ID, CategoriesExtended.Category, CategoriesExtended.Type FROM CategoriesExtended; 

When I utilize a Split Form, when I add first record the cascading and requery works as expected.  When I add a second record, and change the Type field, the Category field requeryed and the first record Category now displays as blank.  The ID is still stored in the underlying table but text no longer displays.
How can I update this so that I display the text and still use the cascading combo boxes as well?
